# C# - Image From Datagrid view to picture box

Tags: c#, datagrid

I have datagrid view with a column type of image. I want to get the value from the datagrid to the picture box that I'm using. Here's my code located in my CellClick

```
byte[] image = (byte[])dgv_salesquotesummary.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[7].Value;
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(image);
pb_productImage.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
```

I got this error that says

```
Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Drawing.Bitmap' to type 'System.Byte[]'.
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The value of that cell is already a Bitmap, so no need to cast them to byte[], just cast it to Image should you need to.

Comment: What do you mean? please create you answer in code format so I can try and test it :)

Comment: pb_productImage.Image = (Image)(((Bitmap)dgv_salesquotesummary.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[7].Value).Clone())

Comment: Sir thank you its working now. Please put your answer on the "Answer" box so I will mark it as "Answered" thank you so much sir!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message shows a failure on casting Bitmap to byte[]. This means the cell Value is a [Bitmap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which derive from Image. In simple types usually you can just use it immediately like this :

```
pb_productImage.Image = (Image) dgv_salesquotesummary.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[7].Value
```

However, since in this case the Image could be disposed at any time by your datagrid, it's prudent to clone the Image first, like :

```
pb_productImage.Image = (Image)(((Bitmap)dgv_salesquotesummary.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[7].Value).Clone())
```

Comment: Very helpful! God bless you sir! + :)